# Laravel + Web Restricción de edad

Tags: php, laravel

Les comento mi problema. Mi polola tiene que realizar un proyecto para su Universidad en el cual consta de una web creaada en laravel jetstream con login, register, CRUD de noticias y una web que te permita visualizar cierto tipo de contenido si eres mayor de edad o no (ej. Si soy menor de edad que solo me muestre 2 imágenes con 2 párrafos y si soy mayor de edad que me muestre 3 imágenes con párrafos).

Esta página también debe incluir un carrusel de imágenes.

Espero haberme explicado bien, yo con los pocos conocimientos que poseeo pude apoyarla con respecto al CRUD de noticias, pero sobre la web con restricción de edad hemos intentado de todo y no hemos dado éxito en ello.

Saludos Cordiales

Comment: Pero cual es el problema que tienes? Al cargar la pagina restringida pregunta primero la edad al usuario, si es mayor muestras una cosa, si es menor muestras otra... no?

Comment: Exactamente es lo que dices.
Primero en el dashboard se muestran dos vínculos a dos páginas webs diferentes una vez el usuario esté autentificado.

En segundo lugar dentro de esos dos vínculos que te indico, debe existir uno con una web que al ingresar solicite confirmar si es mayor o menor de edad y luego de eso visualizar un contenido u otro según edad.

Ahora, una consulta Pipe.
Es posible redireccionar a una web que no está creada en laravel desde el proyecto actual a través de un vínculo integrado en el projecto de laravel.

Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: a que te refieres con "un vínculo integrado en el projecto de laravel"?

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Angelox85 bienvenido a stackoverflow,

lo que debes hacer es agregar a la tabla de usuarios la fecha de cumpleaños o la edad (en numeros) y en las vistas validar si es o no mayor de edad, por ejemplo:

```
@if($user->age >= 18)
  // html que quieres mostrar si el usuario es mayor de edad
@else
  // html que quieres mostrar si el usuario NO es mayor de edad
@endif
```

Espero haberte ayudado, cualquier duda no dudes en escribirme, saludos